# Connecting 2 arduinos via Bluetooth to the same Android flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to connect 2 Arduino to the same mobile app using BLE I have the code for one Arduino connection how to manage it so I can have two Arduino connected
is it possible to connect two Arduinos with BLE to the same app?
Or should I find another alternative

```
void _connectBLE() {

setState(() {
  temperatureStr = 'Loading';
});
_disconnect();
_subscription = _ble.scanForDevices(
    withServices: [],
    scanMode: ScanMode.lowLatency,
    requireLocationServicesEnabled: true).listen((device) {
  if (device.name == 'Arduino3') {
    print('NiclaSenseME found!');
    _connection = _ble
        .connectToDevice(
      id: device.id,
    )
        .listen((connectionState) async {
      // Handle connection state updates
      print('connection state:');
      print(connectionState.connectionState);
      if (connectionState.connectionState ==
          DeviceConnectionState.connected) {
        Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 5), (timer) async{
          final characteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(
              serviceId: Uuid.parse("181A"),
              characteristicId: Uuid.parse("2A6E"),
              deviceId: device.id);
          final response = await _ble.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
          print(response);
          setState(() {
            temperature = fromBytesToInt32(response[0],response[1],response[2],response[3]);
            print(temperature);
            temperatureStr = temperature.toString();

          });

        });
        _disconnect();
        print('disconnected');
      }
    }, onError: (dynamic error) {
      // Handle a possible error
      print(error.toString());
    });
  }
}, onError: (error) {
  print('error!');
  print(error.toString());
});
```

}

Comment: Which BLE library are you using? This should be possible using [flutter_reactive_ble](https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble)

Comment: yes it's reactive BLE but I don't really understand how should I implement the method to connect 2 devices in parallel

Comment: [this](https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble/issues/94) issue explains that you can simply open multiple connections without closing them

Comment: do you have any idea how to change the code so I can connect then it's ok if I can't disconnect them